# Populate a list with objects using an interface

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist, interface, abstract

OK so I have a task in JSF and Hibernate where I have to obtain a list of objects depending on the type of message that the user selects from the web page, from a dropdown menu.

Now, all the possible kinds of objects (when I say objects I mean java classes) that the user can select all implement an interface, let's call it `AbstractMessage`.

So I have class `A` that implements `AbstractMessage`, class `B` that implements `AbstractMessage`, `C`, `D` etc.

Now the option for me is, to have many lists of type A, B, C, D etc for each case selected from the dropdown, or use one list of type `AbstractMessage`.

When the user selects one type, say `A`, this `AbstractMessage` list becomes a list of type A. At least, that's the idea - to just use one list of type `AbstractMessage` instead of a ton of lists of type `A` `B` `C` etc.

The question is - how can I do that? I already declared my abstract list as follows:

```
private List<AbstractMessage> abstractList = new ArrayList<AbstractMessage>();
```

How can I make this list become a list of type "A", "B", "C" (depending on the results of an if-else statement, that I already have)?

So everything is in place, but I don't know how can I convert the `abstractList` into an `A`, `B`, `C` type list?

I tried just declaring the list without initializing it, I tried casting, but it doesn't work. There has to be some very simple explanation for this. Thanks.

Comment: You mean the type of the ```abstractList``` variable changes to ```List<A>``` for instance? Or do you just want to assign a ```List<A>``` to ```abstractList```?

Comment: I want `abstractList` to become `List<A>` once the user selects that particular type from the dropdown.

So when I reach that if statement, and we know the user has chosen the type "A", I want the list to become of type "A" so it's `List<A>` (so it's being populated with "A" objects)

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu, Say If user selects A, then create an instance of ArrayList<A> instead of initially initializing the list to hold AbstractMessage.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu, Say If user selects A, then create an instance of ArrayList<A> instead of initially initializing the list to hold AbstractMessage.
I mean private List<AbstractMessage> abstractList = null;
Later somewhere in your method, List<AbstractMessage> abstractList = new ArrayList<A>;

Comment: What do you mean? You mean, I should just declare the `abstractList` like this:

`private List<AbstractMessage> abstractList;`

And then, in the `if` statement, say `abstractList = new ArrayList<A>();` ?

This is what you mean?

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu, Exactly, based upon user selection from dropdown

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. It says **Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<AbstractMessage> to List<A>**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bounded wildcard:

```
List<? extends AbstractMessage> list;
...
list = new ArrayList<A>();
...
AbstractMessage var1 = list.get(0);
A var2 = (A) list.get(0);

List<A> list2 = (List<A>) list;
list2.add(new A());
A var3 = list2.get(0);
```

---

Or in the case you only want to get objects of type `AbstractMessage` from the list:

```
List<AbstractMessage> abstractList = new ArrayList<>();
...
abstractList.add(new A());
AbstractMessage var1 = abstractList.get(0);
A var2 = abstractList.get(0); // <-- Compiler error
A var3 = (A) abstractList.get(0);
...
List<A> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
...
abstractList.addAll(list2);
```

Comment: That's hard for me to follow, it's beyond where my experience is right now. There has to be some very simple solution, though. Since all my classes extend the `AbstractMessage` interface, I should be able to use this declared List for any of them.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu It kind of depends... What do you want to get back when you call ```get```, an object of type ```A``` or an object of type ```AbstractMessage```?

Comment: I want the `List<AbstractMessage>` to become a `List<A>`, when the situation calls for it (when the user has selected the appropiate type "A" from the dropdown menu in the web interface).

So the user selects "A" in the web interface, then I enter an `if-else` statement in my BEAN class, so I enter the `if` code block for the case where the type is "A", and there I want the previously declared `List<AbstractMessage>` to become `List<A>`. That's all. Very simple.

Comment: @RobertRuxandrescu I know what you want, I don't know what you want to use it for, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: What do you mean, "what I want to use it for"? Is that relevant in any way? I want to create this list so that I can use just one list for all my `if-else` statements.

Otherwise I would have to declare a separate list for each one of them. I would have to declare a `List<A>` to use it when the user selects the "A" scenario, a `List<B>` to use it when the user selects the "B" option and so on. Since they all extend the same `interface`, I could use only one `List` of the `interface` type everywhere and populate that once the user makes his choice.